# Counting the number of characters stored wrong for each incorrect password entered

Tags: python

I wrote the script below:

```
numString = []
count = 0
while(True):
    numInput=raw_input("Please enter your password\n")
    count = count + 1
    if numInput!="rusty":
        numString.append(numInput)

    else:
        break

def write_textfile(filename):
    ofile = open('wrongpasswords.txt','w')  
    ofile.write("\nIncorrect password 1:" +  numString[0])
    ofile.write("\nIncorrect password 2:" +  numString[1])
    ofile.write("\nIncorrect password 3:" +  numString[2])
    ofile.write("\nCorrect password entered on " + str(count)+"th entry")
    ofile = open('wrongpasswords.txt', 'r')
    for line in ofile:
            print line
    ofile.close()

ofile = open('wrongpasswords.txt', 'r')   
write_textfile(ofile)
```

to print the following

```
Incorrect password 1: rusty123
Incorrect password 2: Rusty
Incorrect password 3: rustless
Correct password entered on 4th entry.
```

I want to write one that will print the following:

```
Incorrect password 1: rusty123 , wrong by 3 characters.
Incorrect password 2: Rusty , wrong by 1 characters.
Incorrect password 3: rustless , wrong by 4 characters.
Correct password entered on 4th entry.
```

I have tried to use `difflib`.

Comment: Turn off caps lock, shouty.  "Stuck" doesn't help.

Comment: 1. Never hardcode passwords in code, 2. Never give hints as to why a password is incorrect. With a "wrong by n characters" message, I can crack your password in a * b attempts where a is the number of possible characters in each spot (e.g. 255) and b the maximum length.

Comment: Actually (a + 1) * b, allowing for abrupt finish.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Hamming distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

```
def Hamming(a, b):
    K=len(a)

    # Hamming distance is only for pieces of data
    # that are of equal length
    if K!=len(b):
        return -1

    cnt=0
    for x in range(K):
        if a[x]!=b[x]: cnt+=1

    # if the strings are equal, returns zero,
    # number of non-equal characters otherwise
    return cnt
```

Use it in your code like this:

```
correct="rusty"

ofile.write("\nIncorrect password 1: {}, {} characters are incorrect".format(numString[0], Hamming(numString[0], correct)))
```